# Posting a Collection and ModelState

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem in my MVC application that I am not sure how to solve or if I am going about it in the wrong way.

I have a controller/view that displays a list of items in a grid with a checkbox and when the items are posted to my controller, I would like to delete rows from my database based on the id's that were passed in.

The view looks something like this:

```
@for(int index = 0; index < Model.Items.Length; index++)
{
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[index].Id)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[index].Delete)
    </td>
}
```

My controller accepts the values:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(DeleteItemsModel model)
{
    if( !ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        // ...
    }

    foreach( var id in model.Items.Where(i => i.Delete))
        repo.Delete(id);
}
```

This scenario works fine. Items are posting correctly with the id and a flag to delete or not and they are deleted properly. The problem I am having is when my page fails validation. I need to get the items from the database again and send the data back to the view:

```
if( !ModelState.IsValid )
{
    var order = repo.GetOrder(id);

    // map
    return View(Mapper.Map<Order, OrderModel>(order));
}
```

In the time between the user getting a list of items to delete and them clicking Submit, it is possible that new items could have been added. Now when I pull the data and send it back to the view, there could be new items in the list.

Example of the problem:
I do an HTTP GET on my page and there are two items in my grid with Id of 2 and 1. I select the first row (Id 2, sorted by most recent) and then I click Submit. Validation on the page fails and I return the view to the user. There are now three rows in the grid (3, 2, 1). MVC will have the checkbox on the FIRST item (with an id of 3 now). If the user doesn't check this data then they could be potentially deleting the wrong thing.

Any ideas on how to fix this scenario or what should I do instead?
Does anyone have any idea on how to

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow is not in need of your SEO skills](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I will remember this for the future.

Comment: There is a problem in the approach, you should not get items from database on Model validation fail. If you somehow have to, then you need to rebuild your view-model.

Comment: @ElYusubov What if the data is stale? Just update it anyway?

Comment: The problem with not getting the items from the database when validation fails is that I'm not POSTING every single piece of data to the controller so I would have to either start POSTing the data which would be inefficient.

Comment: If you posting partially(in pieces), then consider ajax calls and child actions. That should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. Let's first illustrate the problem with a simple example because judging from the other answers I am not sure that everyone understood what the problem is here.

Suppose the following model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Delete { get; set; }
}
```

the following controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Initially we have 2 items in the database
        var model = new[]
        {
            new MyViewModel { Id = 2 },
            new MyViewModel { Id = 1 }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel[] model)
    {
        // simulate a validation error
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "some error occured");

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // We refetch the items from the database except that
            // a new item was added in the beginning by some other user
            // in between
            var newModel = new[]
            {
                new MyViewModel { Id = 3 },
                new MyViewModel { Id = 2 },
                new MyViewModel { Id = 1 }
            };

            return View(newModel);
        }

        // TODO: here we do the actual delete

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

and a view:

```
@model MyViewModel[]

@Html.ValidationSummary()

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete)
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Delete)
            @Model[i].Id
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
}
```

Here's what will happen:

The user navigates to the `Index` action, selects the first item to delete and clicks on the Delete button. Here's how the view looks like before he submits the form:

[image]

The Delete action is invoked and when the view is rendered once again (because there was some validation error) the user is presented with the following:

[image]

See how the wrong item is preselected?

Why does this happen? Because HTML helpers use the ModelState value in priority when binding instead of the model value and this is by design.

So how to solve this problem? By reading the following blog post by Phil Haack: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

In his blog post he talks about *Non-Sequential Indices* and gives the following example:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Create">

    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="cold" />
    <input type="text" name="products[cold].Name" value="Beer" />
    <input type="text" name="products[cold].Price" value="7.32" />

    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="123" />
    <input type="text" name="products[123].Name" value="Chips" />
    <input type="text" name="products[123].Price" value="2.23" />

    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="caliente" />
    <input type="text" name="products[caliente].Name" value="Salsa" />
    <input type="text" name="products[caliente].Price" value="1.23" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

See how we are no longer using incremental indexes for the names of the input buttons?

How do we apply this to our example?

Like this:

```
@model MyViewModel[]
@Html.ValidationSummary()
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete)
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.Hidden("index", Model[i].Id)
            @Html.Hidden("[" + Model[i].Id + "].Id", Model[i].Id)
            @Html.CheckBox("[" + Model[i].Id + "].Delete", Model[i].Delete)
            @Model[i].Id
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
}
```

Now the problem is fixed. Or is it? Have you seen the horrible mess that the view now represents? We have fixed one problem but we have introduced something absolutely abominable in the view. I don't know about you but when I look at this I want to vomit.

So what could be done? We should read Steven Sanderson's blog post: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ in which he presents a very interesting custom `Html.BeginCollectionItem` helper which is used like this:

```
<div class="editorRow">
    <% using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("gifts")) { %>
        Item: <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %>
        Value: $<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { size = 4 }) %>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Notice how the form elements are wrapped in this helper?

What does this helper do? It replaces the sequential indexes generated by the strongly typed helpers by Guids and uses an additional hidden field to set this index at each iteration.

---

This being said, the problem exhibits only if you need to get fresh data from your database in the Delete action. If you rely on the model binder to rehydrate there won't be any issues at all (except that if there is a model error you will show the view with old data -> which probably is not that problematic after all):

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel[] model)
{
    // simulate a validation error
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "some error occured");

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        return View(model);
    }

    // TODO: here we do the actual delete

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You understood my problem exactly and this is a great solution. I thought I explained it sufficiently but I probably need to work at wording my questions a little better.

Answer (score 0):

The common solution to this problem is to use the [Post-Redirect-Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

You can find an explanation with code sample for MVC [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx) (along with a bunch of other good MVC tips). Scroll down to item 13 on the list for the PRG explanation.

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't solve the problem completely. If a new item is added it will be at the top of the list. The ModelState for the item at index 0 has been checked, and the new item will now be checked.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you didn't make any changes, redirect and re-display the unchanged form. If you do make changes, redirect and display the modified data. From your comment it sounds like you keep some state around from the last request to check the items, rather than fetching the information freshly from your data store or backend, which is what you probably should be doing. If this doesn't help, consider posting a new question with code to show what you're doing now.

Comment: Just came across this post - I think it'll help you solve the problem. See http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/06/persisting-model-state-when-using-prg.html

Comment: Persisiting Model State is the problem. Read the question again please. I have two rows in my table. I click the first checkbox in the first row. Validation fails. I redirect back to the GET and persist model state in my TempData. The database retrieves the data and now there are 3 items instead of two...and the most recently added item to the database is now in the first row. The first item in the table now has a checkbox instead of the correct one.

Comment: The problem is this: ModelState will have an entry basically like this:  Items[0].Delete=true. 0 is the index. If the page is reloaded and a DIFFERENT item is now at index 0, then that ModelState is now basically wrong because it is referring to a different item than what it was first POSTed.

Comment: Stop and think for a moment. If the index isn't constant for items (which you have determined) then perhaps you shouldn't be using it? Do the items have something else you could use? I see an `Id` property; maybe you should use that to find items instead of an index? Pausing and thinking helps, try it ;)

Comment: I'm not using indexes to determine what is what. ASP.net MVC requires form variable names to be in a certain format to post a collection. The problem is when I redisplay the view to the user, things get reordered and MVC is using model state to build the view.